# sum variable in a range (python)

Tags: python, sum, range

This was the question:

> Write a function called sum_range that accepts 2 integer values as
>   parameters and returns the sum of all the integers between the two
>   values, including the first and last values. The parameters may be in
>   any order (i.e. the second parameter may be smaller than the first).
>   For example:
>
> result = sum_range(1, 1) 
>   print(result) 1
>
> result = sum_range(2, 4)    print(result) 9
>
> result = sum_range(3, 2)
>   print(result) 5

my codes are as below, I dont know where it went wrong
but when I test the codes, it returned 'none' when (2,4) (3,2) were entered

```
def sum_range(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return x

    if x<y:
        sum(range(x,y))
        return
    if x>y:
        sum(range(y,x))
        return
```

Comment: You implicitly return `None` in 2 of 3 cases.

Comment: @vaultah what am i supposed to return?

Comment: To quote the question "...and returns the sum ...".

Comment: @Evert i've tried to return sum, but it showed up "<built-in function sum>" not an value of the sum

Comment: Btw, why does (1, 1) result in 1 if it says "including the first and last values". Shouldn't it give 2 (first value + last value = 1 + 1 = 2)?

Comment: Well, you'll need to call the `sum` function, then return the result. You're calling it correctly elsewhere, just not returning it.

Comment: Python has `min(x, y)` and `max(x,y)`. You could replace that whole messy logic with: `return sum(range(min(x,y),max(x,y)+1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close but forgot to return the actual value from the calculations. If you just type "return", you will return None and not the result from the sum.

You also did not include the last number in the range in the sum. See corrected code below:

```
def sum_range(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return x
    if x < y:
        return sum(range(x, y+1))
    if x > y:
        return sum(range(y, x+1))
```

Comment: but what is that +1 for?

Comment: range(a,b) produces a half-open range, i.e. from a (inclusive) up to but not including b. If you want to include b, you need range(a,b+1)

Comment: The upper bound of the range is not included, if you don't write the +1 sum_range(2,4) would be 5 and not 9

Comment: @Andrew oh~ I get it. Thank you so much :))

Answer (score 1):

You could do better (at least I think), here is my code for that:

```
def sum_range(a, b):
  return sum(range(min(a,b),max(a,b)+1))
```

Comment: There's no need for the base case - `range(a, a+1)` will iterate over only `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the sum which you are not doing in the `x<y` and `x>y` cases. You should

`return sum(range(x,y))` or `return sum(range(y,x))` as appropriate.

Note also that there is a bug in your `range()` expressions - "including the first and last values". Hint: What does `range(1,3)` output?

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_range(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return x
    elif x < y:
        s = 0
        for i in range(x,y):
            s += x+(x+1)
        return s
    elif x > y:
        s = 0
        for i in range(y,x):
            s += y+(y+1)
        return s
```

This is done without using sum() function.